# Google signin issue

Tags: android, google-signin

My code for login with google is working fine in all device except XIAOMI MI 3W(os 6.0.1). In XIAOMI MI 3W UI is freezed not even opening account chooser dialog. It changes statusbar color so I guess it open the dialog but didn't visible.

I used this code for google login

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(Constant.GOOGLE_AUTH_KEY)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

for request intent

```
  Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, Constant.REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
```

my on activity result code is

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: MIUI sometime somehow corrupts some of the google play services, please make sure google sign in is working from other applications

Comment: yes its working in pokemon go

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **google account manager** in your XIOAMI phone? in XIOAMI by default there is no google account manager. This also could  be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your google play services enable or not?
If google play services is disable please enable it.
Then it work completely.